# Vue 3, GraphQL, Apollo - How to re-render query when cache changes?

Tags: vue.js, graphql, vuejs3, apollo

I would like to know how to build Vue 3 Apollo apps with *queries* and *mutations*. I'm familiar with react `useQuery` hook. It re-renders the component whenever the cached data has been changed (by mutations).

I have tried:

- useQuery (https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/api/use-query.html)
- ApolloQuery (https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide-components/query.html)

In all cases it just loads the data once and doesnt react to cache data changes.

I undestand that I can build own setup by Apollo client or refetch the *queries*. I can even invalidate components by its keys. This is not really as elegant as the React `useQuery` hook is.

I was curious whether there is any ready-made solution and the best practice for smooth graphql operations in Vue 3.

Comment: Could you please provide a code sandbox showing what you are doing so we can play with the code?

Comment: I noticed that was my fault, I have set the cache policy wrong, I will answer the question by my own, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have misconfigured the schema and cache update. So the answer is that it works well.

For example:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="loading">...loading</div>
  <div v-else-if="error">{{ error.message }}</div>
  <div v-else>{{value}}</div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import gql from "graphql-tag";
  import { GetValueQuery } from "./ValueComponent.generated";
  import { useQuery, useResult } from "@vue/apollo-composable";

  const GetValue = gql`
    query getValue {
      value
    }
  `;

  function useGetValue() {
    const { result, loading, error } =
      useQuery<GetValueQuery>(GetValue);
    const value = useResult(result, null, (data) => data.value);
    return { value, loading, error };
  }

  const { value, loading, error } = useGetScans();
</script>
```

Works the described way - the template is re-rendered once data cache changed (by a mutation with the proper result set or by its `update` function)

So it is not valid question, the bug was in the implementation of cache policy on my side.

Comment: so how did you configured your cache for re-rendering from cache?

Comment: no, i have used default, it works